# Java Game Server thread-safe recieving web-socket messages

Tags: java, multithreading, websocket, server, program-entry-point

I'm upgrading my python websocket game server to Java, (using Jetty for websockets), and recently started to learn about thread safety.

My challenge is, ***the game logic (gameRoom instance) runs on the main thread, but the server will be receiving player messages (eg. a message to join a game room), and notifying the game logic FROM ANOTHER THREAD***. I originally (in python-when all was on the main thread) just processed the message right away, (eg. add a player on recieving a message). This can lead to problems with multiple threads, as the gameRoom thread might be adding a player at the same time, to the players array. (The players list ends up being shared during adding a player= not thread safe!)

**What's the SIMPLEST way to handle recieving messages from a servlet running on it's own threads, and process these messages WITHOUT messing up the game running on the main thread**(a different thread)? In my head, i'd imagine some kind of one-way buffer (eg. http://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa14/classes/20-queues-locks/message-passing/) to queue new messages to be processed ONLY by the gameRoom itself, during part of the logic. Or is there a way to avoid mulitple threads at all!? *Please give your thoughts, I'd love to hear from someone with more than my begginner level of thread knowledge. I greatly appreciate all tips/ advice :) *

I took the time to make a SIMPLE EXAMPLE showing what's going on (please ignore synax errors, i made it super short for your convinience :) ):

```
class ServerClass {
    static GameRoomClass gameRoom;


    static void main() {
        //psuedocode start Jetty Server, this server runs in another thread, will call onServerMessage()
        jettyServer.start();
        jettyServer.onMessageCallback=(onServerMessage); //set message callback (pseudocode)

        //create game room, run on main thread
        gameRoom = GameRoomClass();
        gameRoom.runGameRoom();
    }

    //when the server gets a message from a player,
    //this will be called by the server from another thread, will affect the GameRoom
    static void onServerMessage(Message theMessage) {
        gameRoom.gotServerMessage();
    }
}

//this runs game logic
class GameRoomClass {
    ArrayList<E> players = new ArrayList<>();

    public void runGameRoom() {
        while (true) {
            //move players, run logic...

            //sometimes, may call addNewPlayer AS WELL
            if(...){
                addNewPlayer();
            }
        }

    }

    public gotServerMessage(){
        //this will only be called by the 'Server' thread, but will enter 'addNewPlayer' method
        //meaning it will access shared value players?
        addNewPlayer()
    }

    public addNewPlayer(){
        //this will be called by the server thread, on getting a message
        //can ALSO be called by gameRoom itself
        players.add(new PlayerObj());
    }

}

class PlayerObj {
    //a player in the game
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and efficient way is to use one of thread-safe collection classes from java.util.concurrent package.
For the given case ConcurrentLinkedQueue seems to be a good start.